# Net 4.0 alternative to Task.WhenAny() with 2 tasks?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I'm writing on a client/server based application; the client can request the server to run certain calculations.
The server will launch its calculation on a background thread, and keep sending a heartbeat message every 1 second while its calculating.

In recent net versions, that's fairly easy:

```
            var calculationTask = Task.Run(() => DoTheCalculation());

            while(true)
            {
                Task heartbeatTask = Task.Delay(1000);  // We send a heartbeat every second
                Task combinedTask = Task.WhenAny(calculationTask, heartbeatTask);
                combinedTask.Wait();

            if(calculationTask.IsFaulted || calculationTask.IsCompleted)
                {
        SendResultToClient();
                    break;
                }

                SendHeartbeatToClient();
            }
```

But I am looking to implement the same pattern in Net 4.0 now. Task.Run() and Task.Delay() are relatively easy to fake; but there doesn't appear to be an easy implementation of Task.WhenAny().

Is there any clever to fake this behaviour any other way? I've thought of some other forms of signaling (ManualResetEventSlim), but so far couldn't really think of any way to make this bullet proof.

I am looking for a solution that does not need any other libraries (e.g. no TPL or such).

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just pass a CancellationToken and set it to expire at 1000ms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best alternative for this in .NET 4.0 is [`TaskFactory.ContinueWhenAny`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.continuewhenany(v=vs.110).aspx).

You generally call this using:

```
Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAny(yourArrayOfTasks, yourActionWhenAnyHere);
```